# Printing Bills In Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, printing, billing

I have made a Billing software in Java ( Using Netbeans ) , All the components are working perfectly now , except the Printing section ...

I want to **Draw a bill** ( With the Store Name , Address , etc ... ) , **Add the values** of the jTable ( Containing sales details ) , and also a **Footer** ( containing Date , Time , etc ) ...

Can anyone please guide me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dedicated library like [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial). It will get much easier after and their guide is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks Ion Cojocaru , It worked perfectly fine ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested panels. Use JPanel class.
Strategy can be to use 1 Main Panel for whole of the bill.
Add 3 different panels to this main panel.
Add Header ( Draw a bill ( With the Store Name , Address , etc ... )) to first panel.
Sales info inside a JTable. Add this table to seconed panel. 
Similarly add Footer to the last panel.
Refer this link for [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).